# Play sound file on div display

Tags: javascript

I have the following JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/**
* @param {string} filename without extension //chat sound
*/
function playSound(filename){   
    document.getElementById("sound").innerHTML='<audio autoplay="autoplay"><source src="' + filename + '.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" /><source src="' + filename + '.ogg" type="audio/ogg" /><embed hidden="true" autostart="true" loop="false" src="' + filename +'.mp3" /></audio>';
}

</script>
```

The code plays a sound file on button click which is working fine.

```
<button onclick="playSound('inc/sound');">Play</button>  
<div id="sound"></div>
```

I have another div as follows:

```
<div id="acceptCallBox">
    <!-- Should be initially hidden -->
    <div id="acceptCallLabel"></div>
    <input type="button"  id="callAcceptButton" value="Accept" /> 
    <input type="button"  id="callRejectButton" value="Reject" />
</div>
```

It is hidden by default (display: none;). I need to play the sound when the div is displayed. How is it possible. Requesting help...

Comment: It depends when div is displayed

Comment: Where exactly are you calling `.play()` an on which `audio` element?

Comment: It is a function function playSound and the sound file is sound.ogg and sound.mp3. The button click works fine...But not Div display..

Comment: What about `MutationObserver`?

Comment: Yes..i will try it..Is style.display != "none" correct usage...because it is working even without div display ???

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the `<div>` is displayed and then tell the audio file to start playing as shown below:

```
var acceptCallLabel = document.getElementById("acceptCallLabel");
var audio = document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0];

if (acceptCallLabel.style.display != "none") {
    audio.play();  /* Make the audio start playing */
}
```

Comment: Have you even made the div to appear after on some event?

Comment: Not from same page. A button click on another page displays the div on the current page...Chat request...

Comment: Wrap my code into a function and call it onclick of your button along with your script of showing the hidden and it should work.

Comment: It is already working fine with button click. It is not based on click event. rather a div being displayed based on event at another page and passed through websockets

Comment: To clear this up, does the `div` appear at all after the click?

Comment: Yes..the div appears..But no sound on display.

Comment: if (acceptCallLabel.style.display != "block") {
    console.log("Display set:");
}

On page load console displays Display set, even without display being shown.

Comment: I said `acceptCallLabel.style.display != "none"` not `"block"`.

Comment: It was a typo...The issue is with "!= "none""

Answer (score 0):

Are you open to using jQuery as an alternative to your approach? Here is an example:

```
<a class="hiddensounddivclick" data-box="#hiddensounddiv" href="#">Click this to show div and play sound</a>    

<div class="hiddensound" data-sound="alert" id="hiddensounddiv">
    HIDDEN DIV
</div>


<!-- START PRELOADS -->
<audio id="audio-alert" src="audio/alert.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
<!-- END PRELOADS --> 



<script>
    /* PLAY SOUND FUNCTION */
    function playAudio(file){
        if(file === 'alert')
            document.getElementById('audio-alert').play();

    }
    /* END PLAY SOUND FUNCTION */


        jQuery(".hiddensounddivclick").on("click",function(){
            var box = $($(this).data("box"));
            if(box.length > 0){
                box.toggleClass("open");

                var sound = box.data("sound");

                if(sound === 'alert')
                    playAudio('alert');


            }        
            return false;
        });
</script>

<style>
.hiddensound {
    display: none;
}

.hiddensound.open {
    display: block;
}
</style>
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/wdp286q3/5/

You would just need to set the audio src to whatever it is in your directory.

Comment: Sorry...I am new to javascript and don't know how to adapt this to my requirement.